# Load new css style for div based on part of url

Tags: html, css, url

I have `wwww.my-site.com` - when a user presses the German flag, it will get to `www.my-site.com/de/`. Now, when that URL is shown, I want to change only the font size for my menu. Path to that is `#topnav li a`

I tried with the following:

```
<script>
  if (window.location.pathname('/de') === 0)
    document.write('<style>#topnav li a{font-size: 15px!important;}</style>');
</script>
```

with no success. Please, any help is more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/de') === 0)
```

*pathname* itself is not a function.

Comment: OMG! :) That worked....why is always only one word, one small part of the code....Thanks a lot :)